# API access to Cognito forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any API access to Cognito Forms or are there plans to make that available?

I'm working on a particular form and finding the email notification is significantly delayed and having API access would be a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is yes.

Long answer:

1. You can post form data as JSON to a webhook.  You can set this up under submission settings.
2. You can use our recently announced Zapier integration to connect [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) to hundreds of popular cloud services.  Check out our announcement post for details: http://blog.cognitoapps.com/connect-your-cognito-forms-to-almost-anything-with-zapier
3. We do have an official JSON REST API that we use behind the scenes to support our Zapier integration and WordPress plugin.  We will make this publicly available once we have documentation in place along with usage policies.
4. We switched from SendGrid to Mandrill (the enterprise transactional mail service by MailChimp) in order to eliminate delivery lag.  We have had customers report delays but these have not been a result of Cognito Forms or Mandrill.  If you are experiencing delays, please send us a bug report and we will research email delivery timing for your organization.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this question. It has been a while since you answered this and since then the api has not been published. Is there any chance, that this will happen soon? I do want to pull the responses from your server and not integrate it with my applications via zapier.

Comment: The integrations you offer don't seem to support fetching existing data on demand. Webhooks are no good for existing data. And Cognito Forms' export tools do not include attachments (come on!)